# Mapping Standard Edition DB Instance to Standard Edition 2 Version - Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-migration

One of our Development Server is running with Oracle SE. The v$version, gives the result as,

`Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

In the same server, I have installed Oracle SE2 version, in a different folder. The v$version, gives the result as,

`Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

Both are working fine independently.

Is there any possibilities, to map the Older DB Instance with Newly Installed Oracle Version.?

or should i need to create a new DB instance, and import the older data.?

Comment: you can't mapping the database you have in SE1 to the new sofware of SE2. if your database is small, I would create a new database in SE2 and then use datapump to migrate the data from the first one to the second one. There are other options, of course, but I think this is the easiest one. Keep in mind you have only to export the schemas that are not oracle maintained, so the ones that contains your application(s) data

Comment: Thanks Much. Its a 3TB Database. Which means, i need to create a similar environment.

Comment: then, you have to go for an upgrade in place. Follow the guide https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/upgrade/overview/upgrading-oracle-database-wp-122-3403093.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upgrade to 12.2.0.1.0. This is a lot quicker than export/import actions and also requires less space.

Start reading the documentation [Upgrading with Oracle Database Upgrade Assistant (DBUA)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/upgrading-oracle-database-upgrade-assistant-dbua.html#GUID-BBF591A5-EB02-405A-9F99-572429838C73) given the question I guess that DBUA, the DataBase Upgrade Assistent is a nice help.

you can also do this manually. This comes down to

1. run the pre upgrade checks using the scripts from the new version. See new $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/preupgrd.sql
2. check the results of step 1 and fix what is needed. preupgrade_fixups.sql can help with some issues.
3. if your database is ready for the upgrade shutdown immediate
4. edit your /etc/oratab and reload your environment with oraenv
5. copy your spfile and paswd files to the new ORACLE_HOME/dbs directory
6. startup upgrade
7. run $ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbupgrade
8. run postupgrade_fixups.sql if needed

A more complete write down can be found by Tim [Upgrading to Oracle Database 12c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/upgrading-to-12c)

Don't forget that the upgrade procedure leaves the database files on their original location. A backup is recommended.